# Fail when accessing std::xxx under clang++

Tags: mingw, clang, llvm, mingw32, clang++

I am using `clang 3.4.1` running under `windows` and `mingw32 (gcc 4.8.1)`.

I have no problem with compiling C program under `clang` and running it. I also have no problem compiling C++ program through `clang++`. But I have problem running the resulting C++ program. It failed with an error stating that the program has halted. I am pretty sure that it has got something to do with the `std::` as it failed whenever I invoked any functions in the std.

Here is my simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "hello, world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled with this command:

```
clang++ Hello.cc -o Hello.exe
```

Any advice?

edit: I discovered that if I `std::cout << "hello, world!\n"`, it terminated gracefully. But `std::cout << "count: " << count` produced the same error.

Apparently, it failed in `libstdc++-6.dll`. Unfortunately, I have no source code.

```
6FC59018  push        ebp  
6FC59019  mov         ebp,esp  
6FC5901B  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
6FC5901E  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
6FC59021  lock xadd   dword ptr [eax],edx                ; Failed here
6FC59025  mov         eax,edx  
6FC59027  pop         ebp  
6FC59028  ret
```

Comment: What was the actual error? What does the debugger say?

Comment: A dialog popped up saying "Hello.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly..."